# Insert into view returns 2 rows affected

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, view, insert

In Sql Server 2005, I have two databases. In the first one I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SG](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [sgName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [hiddenf] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

In the second, I have a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[SG] AS   
    SELECT id,sgName, active 
    FROM [FirstDatabase].dbo.SG WHERE hiddenf = 1
```

with a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[InsteadTriggerSG] on [dbo].[SG] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO [FirstDatabase].dbo.SG(sgName,active,hiddenf)
   SELECT sgName,COALESCE (active,0), 1 FROM inserted 
END
```

When I insert into the view:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
{
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SG(sgName, active) VALUES('Test', 1)", connection);
   var affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   Assert.AreEqual(1, affectedRows);
}
```

I get affectedRows equal to two, while my expected value is 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of question usually makes me think "triggers".

I have just created an exact copy of your scenario (thanks for the detailed instructions) and I am kind of seeing similar results.

By kind of, I meant that when I execute the insert, SSMS outputs

> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

but when I checked the original database, only one row had been added.

To solve your problem, do this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[InsteadTriggerSG] on [dbo].[SG] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS BEGIN 
   SET NOCOUNT ON -- adding this in stops it from reporting from in here
   INSERT INTO [TEST].dbo.SG(sgName,active,hiddenf)
   SELECT sgName,COALESCE (active,0), 1 FROM inserted 
END
```

The issue is that both the trigger and the actual table on the original database are reporting that they've updated a row.  If you remove this reporting from the trigger, but leave it in the original database, you will always get a true answer, whether you update via the view or straight into the original table directly.